# Is Cloudflare Cache unlimited?

Tags: image, caching, proxy, cloudflare

I've built an image proxy server and I'm using Cloudflare to cache the images (each one has ~30KB). And that's working fine with a few images I have now. However, I intend to have millions of images soon. Will Cloudflare be able to cache all my terabytes of images at the same time? Or there is any known limitation?

Comment: The amount Cloudflare will cache is based on the amount of traffic you are getting, and the plan you are paying for. I don't think the exact amount they will cache is published anywhere, but if you aren't getting a lot of traffic for a specific URL, they will remove it from their cache. You would probably have to pay for the Enterprise plan to get any guarantees from them about caching terabytes of your images. You might also try asking in the Cloudflare forums for more details https://community.cloudflare.com/latest

Answer (score 1):

When a visitor visits your site, your site content is routed through Cloudflare. Cloudflare will **cache** static content, including images, for a limited time.

Cloudflare will cache a lot of images, but **don’t expect it to be unlimited**.

You can find here: [Default Cache Behavior of Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior)

Please to the main answer I've took from here: [Community of Cloudflare](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-cdn-limit-on-images/10030)